# How to send a HTML email with attachment using MailApp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying write code in Google Apps Script to send a HTML email with an attachment to a list of my contacts.
The main error I recieve is with the line

```
    MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailid[i], 
    "test email",
    Message,
    htmlBody: HtmlMessage,
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    );
```

The error is with reference to `htmlBody: HtmlMessage` : *SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 48, file "Code.gs")*

I have tried other methods online including

```
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailid[i],
    subject: "This is a test email",
    htmlBody: HtmlMessage,
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]  
  });
```

I get the error : *Exception: Invalid email: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1456304b (line 51, file "Code")*

The entire Code :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //BASIC DETAILS
  var name = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 3).getValues();
  var emailid = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 3).getValues();
  var company = sheet.getRange(1, 3, 3).getValues();

  //ATTACHMENTS
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').getAs('application/pdf').setName('XXXX.pdf');

  //HTML
  var HtmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html');
  var HtmlMessage = HtmlOutput.getContent();

  //PLAIN TEXT
  var Message = 
    "Dear <?= name ?>,"+"\n"+
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXX"+"\n"+
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX <?= company ?> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+"\n"+
    "XXXX Link: https://www.XXXX/XXXX"+"\n"+
    "XXXX."+"\n"+
    "With Warm Regards,"+"\n"+
    "XXX"+"\n"+
    "Call: XXXXX"+"\n"+
    "Email: XXXX"+"\n";
  var OriginalMessage = Message;
  var OriginalHtmlMessage = HtmlMessage;

  for( var i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++)
  {
    Message = Message.replace("<?= name ?>", name[i]);
    Message = Message.replace("<?= company ?>", company[i]);

    HtmlMessage = HtmlMessage.replace("%name", name[i]);
    HtmlMessage = HtmlMessage.replace("%company", company[i]);

    MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailid[i], 
    "test email",
    Message,
    htmlBody: HtmlMessage,
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
    );

    Message = OriginalMessage;
    HtmlMessage = OriginalHtmlMessage;
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size: 1.5em; padding: 5%;">
    Dear %name,<br>
    <div style="line-height: 2;margin-left:5%;">
        XXXX  XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX.<br>
        XXXX  XXXXXX XXXXX %company XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX. <br>
        XXXX  XXXXXX XXXXX: <a href="https://www.XXXX">Link</a><br>
        I XXXXXX XXXX  XXXXX<br></div>
    <div style="line-height: 1.5; padding: 5%;">
        With Warm Regards,<br>
        <b>XXXXx</b><br>
        <a href="tel:+XX-XXXXX">Call: +XX-XXXXX</a><br>
        <a href="mailto:XX@XXXXXX.com">Email: XX@XXXXXX.com</a><br></div>
</body>

</html>
```

How should the parameters for MailApp.SendMail() be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The method syntax is [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

whereby both `attachments` and `htmlBody` are `options` and `options` are

> a JavaScript object that specifies advanced parameters

So you need to pass the `options` as a JSON object with key-value pairs:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    emailid[i][0], 
    "test email",
    Message,
    {
      htmlBody: HtmlMessage,
      attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    }
  );
```

Comment: I have tried that before. I get _Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail._

Comment: This is because there is some problem with the values - they are not of the required datatype. It should be `emailid[i][0]` and not `emailid[i]` (value, not array).  Check also that your html output and file are correct.